# Checking character properties in Java

Tags: java

Alright, I'm coding this program that will discard any characters that are not letters.  And right now I am having trouble trying to have the program identify which is which. Here's some of the code I did.

```
System.out.println("Press enter every time, you type a new word, and press the period button to end it.");
Scanner question = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Press enter to continue, or tupe something random in");
String userInput = question.next();
while(!userInput.equals(".")){
    String userInput2 = question.next();
    System.out.println(userInput2);

    if(userInput2.equals("Stop")){
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to remove all characters which are not either lowercase or uppercase letters:

```
String userInput2 = question.next();
userInput2 = userInput2.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
System.out.println(userInput2);
```

Comment: The unicode class `\p{IsAlphabetic}` might be a better choice for regular expression matching, if the input might contain values outside of US-ASCII. See [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: This possibility didn't occur to me as I assumed it was an English language program.  Thanks for the comment, and I just learned something new on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the string and call [`Character.isLetter(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(char)) for each char to test if it is a letter character.